# Strange behavior when copying an array Java in static method

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have a problem with creating a copy of an array in Java.

I pass a copy of the received data to my custom sort method. 
The problem is the original array changes too. I 've tried with `.clone()` and with some other methods which I found on the internet but the result always was the same: sorted array. I think it's specific for java behaviour and it's super easy to fix. Probably something with static keyword (?). Normally I'm programming in JS, Java is not for me :(

```
    public static void mySort(Example[] data) {
        Example[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
        Example[] sortedArray= customSort(copy);
        System.out.println("Original data (should not be sorted): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

How to create a true copy of the received data in mySort method?

All code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example examples[] = new Example[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
            int randomValue1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
            double randomValue2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
            examples[i] = new Example(randomValue1, randomValue2);
        }

        System.out.println("Beforesort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + examples[i]);
        }

        mySort(examples);
    }

    public static void mySort(Example[] data) {
        Example[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
        Example[] sortedArray= customSort(copy);
        System.out.println("Original data (should not be sorted): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }

// you can ignore this, it's just customSort
    static Example[] customSort(Example[] copy) {

        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < copy.length - i - 1; j++)
                if (copy[j].value1 != copy[j + 1].value1) {
                    if (copy[j].value1 > copy[j + 1].value1) {
                        int temp = copy[j].value1;
                        copy[j].value1 = copy[j + 1].value1;
                        copy[j + 1].value1 = temp;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (copy[j].value2 > copy[j + 1].value2) {
                        double temp = copy[j].value2;
                        copy[j].value2 = copy[j + 1].value2;
                        copy[j + 1].value2 = temp;
                    }
                }


        }
        return copy;
    }

}

class Example {
    int value1;
    double value2;

    public Example(int value1, double value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example{" +
                "value1=" + value1 +
                ", value2=" + value2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're actually not sorting the order of `Example` objects in the passed array to `customSort`, but you are "sorting" by changing the values of the `Example` objects. Are you aware of that? Do you want that?

Comment: @akuzminykh I want to pass a copy of `data` into `customSort` method. The original array (`data`), should not be changed.

Comment: I know, but this is exactly what you are doing. You are sorting by swapping the values of `value1` fields between `Example` instances. This affects the instances themselve, rather than the *position* of the instances in the passed array. Do you get the problem? You are not changing the position of elements, you are changing their content. If it's still unclear, I may need to write an answer.

Comment: I understand a bit. But I don't know exactly how to do it. If you wrote the answer, I would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are sorting by swapping the *content* of the `Example` instances. Imagine those instances with the corresponding values (just in an abstract way):

```
e1 = 3;
e2 = 1;
e3 = 2;
```

You are swapping the *values*, not the *positions* of the instances.

```
e1 = 1;
e2 = 2;
e3 = 3;
```

You can see that the *values* are sorted, but this hasn't affected the position of instances. Every array that references those instances will obviously see those changes as the *values* are changed, not the *position* in the sort array.

What you need is:

```
e2 = 1;
e3 = 2;
e1 = 3;
```

As you can see, the order itself is changed, not whatever an instance contains. This will obviously only be visible in the one array, the one you swap the instances in.

Your sorting function has to be like so:

```java
    static Example[] customSort(Example[] copy) {

        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < copy.length - i - 1; j++)
                if (copy[j].value1 != copy[j + 1].value1) {
                    if (copy[j].value1 > copy[j + 1].value1) {
                        Example temp = copy[j];
                        copy[j] = copy[j + 1];
                        copy[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (copy[j].value2 > copy[j + 1].value2) {
                        Example temp = copy[j];
                        copy[j] = copy[j + 1];
                        copy[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }


        }
        return copy;
    }
```

Again, your current version swaps *values* not *positions*. I hope that's clear now.

---

Here's the whole thing:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example examples[] = new Example[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
            int randomValue1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
            double randomValue2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
            examples[i] = new Example(randomValue1, randomValue2);
        }

        System.out.println("Beforesort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + examples[i]);
        }

        mySort(examples);
    }

    public static void mySort(Example[] data) {
        Example[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
        Example[] sortedArray= customSort(copy);
        System.out.println("Original data (should not be sorted): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + data[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + sortedArray[i]);
        }
    }

// you can ignore this, it's just customSort
    static Example[] customSort(Example[] copy) {

        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < copy.length - i - 1; j++)
                if (copy[j].value1 != copy[j + 1].value1) {
                    if (copy[j].value1 > copy[j + 1].value1) {
                        Example temp = copy[j];
                        copy[j] = copy[j + 1];
                        copy[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (copy[j].value2 > copy[j + 1].value2) {
                        Example temp = copy[j];
                        copy[j] = copy[j + 1];
                        copy[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }


        }
        return copy;
    }

}

class Example {
    int value1;
    double value2;

    public Example(int value1, double value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example{" +
                "value1=" + value1 +
                ", value2=" + value2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```